# Merge json objects with java

Tags: java, json

I have two JSON files. I want to combine them into one in such a way that the second file has a greater priority. That is:

- if 1 has the property `foo` and 2 has no property `foo`, 3 will have the property `foo` with the value from 1.
- if 2 has the property `foo` and 1 has no property `foo`, 3 will have the property `foo` with the value from 2.
- if 1 and 2 both have the property `foo`, 3 will have the property `foo` with the value from 2.

I need to do this in Java. The final JSON object will be deserialized to a Java object with Google Gson.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Remember to include what you've tried and what you know about why it didn't work. Refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
//read both jsons
Map<String, Object> json1 = gson.fromJson("<json1>", Map.class);
Map<String, Object> json2 = gson.fromJson("<json2>", Map.class);
//create combined json with contents of first json
Map<String, Object> combined = new HashMap<>(json1);
//Add the contents of first json. It will overwrite the values of keys are 
//same. e.g. "foo" of json2 will take precedence if both json1 and json2 have "foo" 
combined.putAll(json2);
gson.toJson(combined);
```

Comment: I think this is the reverse of what the OP wanted, but is trivial to correct.

Comment: Corrected the logic :)

Answer (score 0):

To deep-merge JSON files with custom priorities and return as Gson, you should use **confectory-datamapper-gson** https://github.com/oswaldobapvicjr/confectory/wiki/Download.

Here's how you could do it:

```java
Configuration<JsonObject> json1 = Configuration.<JsonObject>builder()
                .mapper(new GsonJsonObjectMapper())
                .source("classpath://file1.json")
                .precedence(9) // Higher priority
                .build();

Configuration<JsonObject> json2 = Configuration.<JsonObject>builder()
                .mapper(new GsonJsonObjectMapper())
                .source("classpath://file2.json")
                .precedence(1) // Lower priority
                .build();

JsonObject merged = json1.merge(json2).getBean();
```